# Use only external monitor at screen's native resolution

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, resolution

My laptop's screen lamp just died (I can see content on the screen if I point a light at it) and I was using it with an external monitor. I can switch from extended desktop to mirrored mode but, and here is where I need help, the resolutions don't match.

The laptop's resolution is 1600x1200 and the external monitor is 1680x1050. I am ok with just using one screen ATM but I would like for it to at least use the native resolution of the external monitor.

This is Windows XP and under Monitor settings I only get the resolutions for the original monitor under mirrored mode. How can I force the screen into a resolution not supported by the laptop screen but that is a native resolution for the external monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to make the external monitor the primary.

If it lets you do that and you still can't choose the resolution you want, disable the mirroring and be careful not to put anything on the "dark" desktop.